# How to get width of each input with specified class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so I have fairly simple thing but something is not working properly.

The first thing I have is a couple of `<input />` buttons and what I want is to set automatically width for each button wrap.

For some reason whatever I try I get the value 0 [3x]. For example something like this...

```
$('.button_holder .proceed').each(function() {
     console.log( parseInt( $(this).outerWidth() ) );
});
```

The console.log gives me "0".

Here's a fiddle for a preview and it works there... Quite odd.

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/b3bMg/1/)

I don't understand why, any tips ?

EDIT 1:
My project has #container set to display: none and JS does some fadeIn effect. Removed that and it appears that it is working properly now.

Any ideas why and how to make it work with `fadeIn()` of container ?

Comment: It's on localhost, and I have just copied everything to the fiddle. Works there, not working on my project.

Comment: When the element is set to `display:none` the element is technically not present on the page. So the width will be `0`.. If you want it to work write your code in the callback of `fadein`

Comment: @Zenith made one small edit to my question.

Comment: @NenaddvL What Sushanth said..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the element is set to **display:none** the element is technically not present on the page. So the `width will be 0`.. If you want it to work write your code in the `callback of fadein`

```
$('#container').fadeIn( 300, function() {
     $('.button_holder .proceed').each(function() {
        console.log( parseInt( $(this).outerWidth(), 10 ) );
     });
});
```

So after the container is visible on the page, which is in the callback function , iterate over the elements and it should work fine.

And don't forget to add the **radix parameter** when you use `parseint`